# View merge conflict for submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repository called "parent", and within this I have a submodule. I have branched both. My friend made changes to the main branch of both. I merged in the changes to the submodule and pushed to my submodule branch. I am now trying to merge the changes in parent, but this has caused a merge conflict. I can see this when I do "git status", where I see: "both modified" next to the submodule directory name. How do I diff this conflict, which I expect to show the uuid for the last commit on the main branch of the submodule (theirs) and the uuid of my latest commit to the submodule (mine). Then how do I resolve the conflict so that I continue to use my latest commit to my branched submodule before doing add on the submodule name, commit and push?

Answer (score 0):

You have to resolve the merge conflict in the submodule first. Just like a standalone repository, you need to change directory (cd) to the submodule, and merge together whatever branches or changes you’re dealing with. However you decide to do that (merge, rebase, cherry-pick, etc.), you just need to end up with one commit that has the files & changes you wanted.

Once you know what your desired submodule commit is, go to the super project and do the merge. Then, while in the merge conflicted state, you can use `git diff -u` and `git ls-files -u` to see the SHA1 of the submodule commits. Look at the documentation or ProGit book regarding the specifics of what the `-u` flag does.
To resolve the merge conflict at the super project level, you can change directory (cd) to the submodule, and checkout the desired submodule commit that I mentioned earlier. You can do so using a branch with `git switch <branch>`, or you can just specify the commit directly with `git checkout <commit>`. The super project doesn’t care about what branch the commit was on - it only records the commit, so apart from remote tracking branches, submodule branches don’t really matter at the super project level.
Then, go back up to the super project and re-add the submodule (`git add <submodule-path>`) to stage the submodule with the commit you wanted.
You can use `git diff —cached` to see the submodule commit you staged.
Run `git commit` and you should be done.